# Domain Privacy Protection based in US

Tags: domains, whois, privacy

*I just received an email from a customer, telling me they heard a rumour that my site wasn't legit and that it was run out of Panama. Noticeably upset, they asked me to explain...*

Upon further investigation, I discovered the following:

- My site is registered and hosted by NameCheap Inc, which is a US company
- When I acquired the domain I clicked the box to use their "WhoisGuard" privacy protection service so that my personal information would not be revealed
- WhoisGuard however, is a Panama company...
- Therefore, the official Whois database for my domain says Panama.

I contacted NameCheap and they explained that as long as I want to use their privacy protection service, it will say Panama and they have no alternative to that.

**So my question is, is there a different registrar that provides a US-based privacy protection service, using a US-based entry in the Whois database?**

Comment: Clarification: hosting providers don't provide domain privacy - registrars do. So, you would only need to switch registrars in order to use a U.S.-based domain privacy service, and point DNS to NameCheap if you wish to keep them as the web host.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Domains' privacy guard uses a Toronto, CA address. If your clients are that worried about your identity, it might make sense to remove privacy protection and list either your real address or a PO box.

Comment: @WebElaine Thank you for pointing out the difference regarding hosting providers vs registrars. As far I as understand it, NameCheap is both a registrar and a hosting provider. I have updated the question.

Comment: @WebElaine clarification: any company could provide domain privacy, there is almost nothing technical to it. It may make (business) sense for registrars to do it by themselves but a customer could as well use any other independent company for the same result. Big corporations often use their attorneys details in whois...

Comment: "Noticeably upset, they asked me to explain" Explain to them that a domain is not a website, and that whatever is displayed in whois has no technical consequences on where the website is physically hosted (which is less and less a real question anyway with cloud services spanning continents) nor where is the underlying company registered. A Panana company could as well host a website in US with a whois showing US addresses, and that gives no more (and no less) guarantees that the business is legit by itself. In short: it is not whois content that determinate if a business is legit or not.

Comment: Only important/interesting point that could raise eyebrows: privacy/proxy services are more natural for individual than corporations. Why would a company need to obfuscate its headquarter address in whois output? This could be by itself a source of concern, but whatever the privacy service address is, this is just irrelevant, it is only the fact of using one for a corporation that, in many parts of the world, should be public with public ways to check its registration, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek "The point for us to remember is: the world does not run on facts and reason. It runs on passion and emotions. " Meaning technicalities won't matter to the average non tech-savvy person. If it says "Panama", some people will associate that with "not legit".

Comment: I perfectly understand your question. I don't understand their concern exactly. What is their issue? "I heard a rumor your site isn't legit." "Well, I can assure you it is my site and it is 'legit'." Do they feel that because of the Panamanian address something nefarious is going on?

Comment: @Ben Some people do all kind of crazy associations and misinterpretations... which is not a reason to just not to educate them. Again: even if the address was "White House, DC, USA" it does not give any more or less indication of the fact that the underlying business is legit or not. Give a man a fish he eats once, teach him how to fish, he eats for his life...

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Well, it's a new site in a fairly small niche, so I think what happened was that someone else (potentially a competitor) checked the Whois database and then told this customer that my site wasn't legit. Fortunately for me, rather than spreading it, the customer got in touch and I could easily clarify by explaining further. However, I can perfectly understand where they are coming from and I want it changed to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: This is still not clear to me: "received an email from a customer" vs "my personal information would not be revealed".  You are providing a service as an individual and not a company OR you registered the domain name with your info instead of the company one? In second case you should instead fix the registration and remove the use of privacy service, which also solve the problem... except if your company is itself truely headquarted in Panama :-)

Answer (score 1):

The privacy address that we (Dynadot) use is located in the United States.  California actually.   As noted by previous posters, you would need to move your domain to a new Registrar if you want to use a different privacy provider.

Before GDPR, I would say that a business should probably have their address on the Whois record.  However, since all contact information is obscured, I'm not sure it matters much and I think your customers complaint is much ado about nothing.